# How to set custom user-agent for Mechanize in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mechanize

I know you have a set of pre-defined aliases you can use by setting agent.user_agent_alias = 'Linux Mozilla' for instance, but what if I want to set my own user agent, as I'm writing a web crawler and want to identify it, for the sites I'm indexing's sake. Just like Googlebot.

There seems to be a user_agent method, but I can't seem to find any documentation about it's function.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can set the user agent from an alias

```
a = Mechanize.new
a.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
```

Available aliases are stored in the `AGENT_ALIASES` constant.

```
p Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES
```

Otherwise, use `#user_agent` to set your custom user agent.

```
a = Mechanize.new
a.user_agent = 'Custom agent'
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might be it, but couldn't find confirmation.

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a way to set a random user agent for Mechanize, so I ended up doing this:

```
a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = (Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES.keys - ['Mechanize']).sample
end
```

Comment: I get this `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method user_agent_alias for #<Mechanize:0x007fd9f6c695f8>` error instead...

Comment: should be  

  a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
    agent.user_agent = Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES[(Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES.keys - ['Mechanize']).sample]
  end

Answer (score 1):

As replied by @Arkhitech, now you would want to do:

```
  agt = Mechanize.new 
  agt.agent.user_agent = Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES[(Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES.keys - ['Mechanize']).sample]
```

`user_agent_alias` is not available any more.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get a new Agent, that is not mechanize

```
Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES[(Mechanize::AGENT_ALIASES.keys - ['Mechanize']).sample]
```