# Unable to access a website using mechanize in Python

Tags: python, mechanize

```
import mechanize

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_refresh(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.open(url)
```

This is the piece of code I am using to open the website but the code keeps running giving "Timeout error"

Comment: This might be a user-agent problem. Some websites will detect it and not let you connect. Try modifying your user-agent to see if that helps.

Comment: Thank for the reply. Can you please guide on how user-agent can be modified?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003039/how-to-set-custom-user-agent-for-mechanize-in-rails